# What do I need to modify in my Web API config file in order to accommodate multiple get methods in my controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API where I have more than one get method in the controller

Below is my code:

My repository class:

```cs
public class myRepository
{

    public myClasses.Type[] GetAllTypes()
    {

        return new myClasses.Type[]
        {
            new myClasses.Type 
            {
                typeId="1",
                typeVal = "New"
            },
            new myClasses.Type 
            {
                typeId="2",
                typeVal = "Old"
            }
       };

    }

    public myClasses.Employee[] GetAllEmployees()
    {

        return new myClasses.Employee[]
        {
            new myClasses.Employee 
            {
                empId="111111",
                empFName = "Jane",
                empLName="Doe"
            },
            new myClasses.Employee 
            {
                empId="222222",
                empFName = "John",
                empLName="Doe"
            }
       };

    }

    public bool VerifyEmployeeId(string id)
    {

        myClasses.Employee[] emp = new myClasses.Employee[]
        {
            new myClasses.Employee 
            {
                empId="111111",
                empFName = "Jane",
                empLName="Doe"
            },
            new myClasses.Employee 
            {
                empId="222222",
                empFName = "John",
                empLName="Doe"
            }
       };

        for (var i = 0; i <= emp.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (emp[i].empId == id)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and my model class:

```cs
public class myClasses
{

    public class Employee
    {
        public string empId { get; set; }
        public string empFName { get; set; }
        public string empLName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Type
    {
        public string typeId { get; set; }
        public string typeVal { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is my controller:

```cs
public class myClassesController : ApiController
{
    private myRepository empRepository;

    public myClassesController()
    {
        this.empRepository = new myRepository();
    }

    public myClasses.Type[] GetTypes()
    {
        return empRepository.GetAllTypes();
    }

    public myClasses.Employee[] GetEmployees()
    {
        return empRepository.GetAllEmployees();
    }

    public bool VerifyEmployee(string id)
    {
        return empRepository.VerifyEmployeeId(string id);
    }
}
```

Everything compiles fine but when I run it using

```
http://localhost:49358/api/myClasses/GetTypes
```

I get an error stating that

> Multiple actions were found that match the request: Type[] GetTypes() on type myProject.Controllers.myClassesController Employee[] GetEmployees() on type myProject.Controllers.myClassesController

Can someone help me update my config file so it would work?

My WebAPIConfig:

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Uncomment the following line of code to enable query support for actions with an IQueryable or IQueryable<T> return type.
        // To avoid processing unexpected or malicious queries, use the validation settings on QueryableAttribute to validate incoming queries.
        // For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=279712.
        //config.EnableQuerySupport();

        // To disable tracing in your application, please comment out or remove the following line of code
        // For more information, refer to: http://www.asp.net/web-api
        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
    }
}
```

Update: Found the answer! Just as I suspected, the fix was in WebApiConfig. I modified the default route and everything worked

Comment: Maybe it is a reserved word...try changing the method name to `GetMyTypes` (For testing purposes)

Comment: Nope, the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! Just as I suspected, the fix was in WebApiConfig. I modified the default route and everything worked

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use Route Attributes to do this (of course, I always use route attributes, I like being explicit).

First, Add this line to your WebApiConfig.cs before any of your declared routes:

`config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`

Then, decorate your controller actions with route attributes and HttpVerbs:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/myClasses/GetTypes")]
public myClasses.Type[] GetTypes()
{
    return empRepository.GetAllTypes();
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("api/myClasses/GetEmployees")]
 public myClasses.Employee[] GetEmployees()
{
    return empRepository.GetAllEmployees();
}
```

You can read more about attribute routing here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: what does config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); do?

Comment: it scans your controllers for route attributes.

Comment: I get errors saying that namespaces RouteAttribute and Route could not be found

Comment: add `using System.Web.Http;` to your controller file.

Comment: Now I get "myProject.Areas.HelpPage.XmlDocumentationProvider' does not implement interface member 'System.Web.Http.Description.IDocumentationProvider.GetResponseDocumentation(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor)"

Comment: that's unrelated to the problem here, it has to do with the auto-generated documentation that WebApi2 provides. If you dont want to use the auto-doc features, you can just delete the /areas/helpPage folder. If you want to use the auto-generated documentation, I suggest you post another question with your error.

Comment: But this error occurred as soon as I added refeence to System.Web.Http needed to fix Namespace RouteAttribute error

Comment: I can't really help you with that because I dont use the help page features. If I were to guess, you are probably using mis-matched versions of `System.Web.Http` and the Help Page namespaces. I suggest just deleting the folder, or commenting out all the code if you want to try and make it work later...